# Removing duplicates every 5 minutes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove duplicate ID's that appear in every 5 minutes time frame from the dataset. The data frame looks something like this;

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Date       |        Time      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |     2012-1-1     |      00:01:00    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          13         |     2012-1-1     |      00:01:30    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |     2012-1-1     |      00:04:30    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |     2012-1-1     |      00:05:10    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |     2012-1-1     |      00:10:00    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Which should become;

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Date       |        Time      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |     2012-1-1     |      00:01:00    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          13         |     2012-1-1     |      00:01:30    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |     2012-1-1     |      00:05:10    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |     2012-1-1     |      00:10:00    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

The second time "12" occurs it should be flagged as duplicate as it appears a second time in the time frame 00:00:00 - 00:05:00.

I am using pandas to clean the current dataset.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from adding *DatTim* column (of type *DateTime*), taking source
data from *Date* and *Time*:

```
df['DatTim'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time)
```

Then, assuming that `ID` is an "ordinary" column (not the index),
you should call:

- `groupby` on `DatTim` column with `5 min` frequency.
- To each group apply `drop_duplicates`, with `subset` including only `ID` column.
- And finally drop `DatTim` from the index.

Expressing the above instruction in Python:

```
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DatTim', freq='5min'))\
    .apply(lambda grp: grp.drop_duplicates(subset='ID'))\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

If you `print(df2)`, you will get:

```
   ID      Date      Time              DatTim
0  12  2012-1-1  00:01:00 2012-01-01 00:01:00
1  13  2012-1-1  00:01:30 2012-01-01 00:01:30
3  12  2012-1-1  00:05:10 2012-01-01 00:05:10
4  12  2012-1-1  00:10:00 2012-01-01 00:10:00
```

To "clean up", you can drop `DatTim` column:

```
df2.drop('DatTim', axis=1)
```

## Edit

If `ID` is the index, a slight change is required:

```
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DatTim', freq='5min'))\
    .apply(lambda grp: grp[~grp.index.duplicated(keep='first')])\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

And then the printed `df2` is:

```
        Date      Time              DatTim
ID                                        
12  2012-1-1  00:01:00 2012-01-01 00:01:00
13  2012-1-1  00:01:30 2012-01-01 00:01:30
12  2012-1-1  00:05:10 2012-01-01 00:05:10
12  2012-1-1  00:10:00 2012-01-01 00:10:00
```

Of course, also in this case you can drop `DatTim` column.